# How to launch without segfault an Intel python3.9 shell on macOS 13.5 Ventura

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, zsh, intel, intel-oneapi

On `MacOS Venture 13.5`, I have installed Intel OneAPI Base and HPC toolkit and also Intel distribution of `python3.9` ( `python 3.9.7`).

I have a strange behavior : if I execute a Python script, everything works fine. But from another side, impossible to launch a python Shell by simply typing "`$ python3.9`".

I have systematically a segfault error by wanting to launch an interactive Shell.

I suspect an issue with environment variables.

If I do a : "`$ env > env_full.txt`" and "`$ env -i PATH="$PATH" env > env_clean.txt`"

The second one returns nothing.

Here the content of `env_full.txt` :

```
TERM_SESSION_ID=w6t0p5:C96747F0-AB9B-4951-9988-3946F864F15E
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.0y5PjBRmV2/Listeners
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.4.20
COLORFGBG=7;0
ITERM_PROFILE=Default
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PWD=/Users/fab
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/zsh
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.googlecode.iterm2
SECURITYSESSIONID=186a2
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.4.20
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/condabin:/Users/fab/bin:/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/bin:/usr/local/opt/qt@5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/fab/bin:/opt/local/bin:/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/libexec/gnubin:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/mac/bin/intel64:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/libexec/qt4/bin/:/Users/fab/bin/:/usr/local/openmpi/bin:/Users/fab/Projets_info/HEAT2D_HEAT3D_PROCESS_PERFORMANCES_26_AVRIL_2012/HEAT3D/Heat3D_MPI_Solving:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin:/usr/local/Healpix_2.15a/bin:/usr/local/skyviewer-1.0.0:/usr/local/matlab/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin:/usr/local/bin
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.FTwTO1Fdl7/org.xquartz:0
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
COLORTERM=truecolor
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
TERM=xterm-256color
HOME=/Users/fab
TMPDIR=/var/folders/1n/6wz8wzkn63n8y1zc2xjcm6640000gn/T/
USER=fab
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
LOGNAME=fab
LaunchInstanceID=A85237BC-3A0E-4FB8-B96A-4EF0A29D2D8B
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x1
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w6t0p5:C96747F0-AB9B-4951-9988-3946F864F15E
SHLVL=1
OLDPWD=/Users/fab
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
CFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CCFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CXXFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
CPPFLAGS=-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
HISTFILE=/Users/fab/.zsh_history
CMPLR_ROOT=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0
NLSPATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2022.2.0/lib/locale/%l_%t/%N:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/mac/compiler/lib/intel64_mac/locale/%l_%t/%N:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/mac/compiler/lib/locale/%l_%t/%N
MANPATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/documentation/en/man/common:
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2022.2.0/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/lib/pkgconfig
MKLROOT=/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2022.2.0
LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib:/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2022.2.0/lib
CPATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2022.2.0/include
OMP_NUM_THREADS=32
PYOPENCL_CTX=:2
G4ENSDFSTATEDATA=/usr/local/share/Geant4-10.2.2/data/G4ENSDFSTATE1.2.3
MATLAB_HOME=/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/
IDL_DIR=/Applications/exelis/idl85
MAP_REF=/home/fab/WMAP/ref
HEALPIX=/usr/local/Healpix_3.20
CLICOLOR=1
LS_COLORS=no=01;37:fi=01;37:di=32:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:ex=00;36:*~=05;31:*.mtxt=05;31:*.ndx=05;31:*.cmd=00;33:*.exe=00;33:*.com=00;33:*.btm=00;33:*.bat=00;33:*.txt=00;37:*.pdf=04;94:*.docx=00;91:*.doc=00;91:*.xlsx=00;91:*.xls=00;91:*.c=00;35:*.h=00;35:*.sh=00;36:*.py=00;36:*.R=00;36:*.cpp=00;35:*.pl=00;36:*.pm=00;35:*.cgi=00;35:*.java=00;35:*.html=00;35:*.tar=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.JPG=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.GIF=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.BMP=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.png=01;35:
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS=false
PYTHONSTARTUP=/Users/fab/.startup.py
SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=0
CONDA_EXE=/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/bin/conda
_CE_M=
_CE_CONDA=
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/bin/python
CONDA_SHLVL=0
_=/usr/local/bin/grc
```

and the content of `env_clean.txt` :

```
PATH=/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/condabin:/Users/fab/bin:/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/bin:/usr/local/opt/qt@5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/fab/bin:/opt/local/bin:/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/libexec/gnubin:/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/mac/bin/intel64:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/libexec/qt4/bin/:/Users/fab/bin/:/usr/local/openmpi/bin:/Users/fab/Projets_info/HEAT2D_HEAT3D_PROCESS_PERFORMANCES_26_AVRIL_2012/HEAT3D/Heat3D_MPI_Solving:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin:/usr/local/Healpix_2.15a/bin:/usr/local/skyviewer-1.0.0:/usr/local/matlab/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Could anyone see what's wrong ?

Comment: Please raise a query in **oneAPI Registration, Download, Licensing and Installation** [here!](https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/bd-p/registration-download-licensing-instal)

Comment: The binary you run when doing `python3.9` seems to be broken. Have a look at this file (for instance with `file =python3.9`). Also verify that you don't have an alias or function masking this file (i.e. `type python3.9`).

Answer (score 0):

2022.2.0 looks as pretty old version, you can try with 2023.x version.
note that MacOS support was removed from 2024.0